# how to make discord bot adapt to other server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, discord

for my discord bot I have hard coded the channel id for the member_leave and member_join. If i wanted to make a command to make it adapt to other server such as when they do -create_join and it will create a member_join in that channel where can i get more info about this ?

I know i am asking too much but please provide me an example of how i can do this ? Many people have recommend me to use postgresql.
code :

```
  WELCOME_ID = 788460126368825355
  LEAVE_ID = 788460140986761227
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):

    channel = client.get_channel(WELCOME_ID)

    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour = 0x99e68b,
        title ='ยินดีต้อนรับเข้าสู่ smilewin !',
        description = 'กรุณาอ่านกฏเเละเคารพกันเเละกันด้วยนะครับ'
        )

    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.avatar_url}")
    embed.set_author(name=f"{member.name}", icon_url=f"{member.avatar_url}") 
    embed.set_footer(text=f"{member.guild}", icon_url=f"{member.guild.icon_url}")
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    embed.set_footer(text='┗Powered by REACT')

    print(f"{member.name} have joined the server {member.guild.name}")
    if member.guild.id == PERSONAL_GUILD_ID:
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
    
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):

    channel = client.get_channel(LEAVE_ID)

    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour=0x983925, 
        title = "Member leave",
        description= f"{member.name}ได้ออกจากเซิฟเวอร์"
        )

    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.avatar_url}")
    embed.set_author(name=f"{member.name}", icon_url=f"{member.avatar_url}") 
    embed.set_footer(text=f"{member.guild}", icon_url=f"{member.guild.icon_url}")
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    embed.set_footer(text='┗Powered by REACT')

    print(f"{member.name} have left the server {member.guild.name}")
    if member.guild.id == PERSONAL_GUILD_ID:
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end what you want is a database to store those channel_id values. One way of doing so would be a JSON as another answer suggested, but if you want to add your bot and use this functionality in many servers, the best would be to use a real database like SQL.

Taking into account that discord.py uses async interface, the best library for starting would be *aiosqlite* (Visit https://github.com/omnilib/aiosqlite).

A simple Python code to store those channel_id in your database would be something like:

```
async def set_channel(self, ctx, channel:discord.TextChannel):
    database = await aiosqlite.connect(database_path)
    cursor = await database.cursor()
    sql = ("UPDATE welcome SET welcome_channel_id = ? WHERE guild_id = ?")
    val = (channel.id, ctx.guild.id)
    await cursor.execute(sql, val)
    await database.commit()
    await cursor.close()
    await database.close()
```

This sample of code already asumes you have your database set up with the tables created, but with a tiny bit of knowledge you should be able to modify this fine.

Comment: What do i need to download ? do i need to download sqlite ?

Comment: You need to install the aiosqlite library (_py -m pip install aiosqlite_). And if you want to navigate through your database, you can use DB Browser for SQLite (https://sqlitebrowser.org/). First step would be to create your database and add the tables that you will want to use. This can be done manually. in the DB Browser.

Answer (score 0):

Well I suggest you to use a json file to store all the channel IDs like this:

```
{
    "guild_id_here": {
        "join_channel": joinchannel_id,
        "leave_channel": leave_channel_id
    }
}
```

you can use the [Python Json Module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to do reading and writing on the document.